# Reprocess historical data on Airflow

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am in a middle of migrating some pipelines to airflow. I want to be able to run some DAGs on for specific time ranges for historical loads and I am exploring my options. Note: I don't want to re-execute previous runs (for example past 10 days) but I want to be able to reload data based on a last_loaded timestamp variable (e.g. 2017-12-09 00:00:00.000000) anytime I need (even before DAGs were created). This variable is also used externally to call APIs.

In total there are 4 concepts in my mind:

1. The current dag run implements exchanging this variable by xcom table in metadata db. Although every time I want to modify it I have to update a fields which data type is blob. I am not even sure if this is possible.
2. Keep this parameter somewhere else. Easy solution to implement but I don't want to reinvent wheel. If there is always some functionality implemented by airflow I would like to explore it.
3. Airflow variables: so far maybe no the most approved concept of airflow but I do feel that this is what I want.
4. Backfill: if I am not mistaken this is attached to the previous executions. So, if my dag started running daily at December I won't be able to load data from August.

Any advice please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this use case you can process the ETL as follows:

1. Read last last_loaded value from Variable.
2. Run ETL between last_loaded to current_timestamp or execution_date or whatever higher boundary of your choice.
3. Store the higher boundary into the Variable.

A skeleton overview could be:

```
def set_dag_variables(**kwargs):
    new_value = kwargs['var_value']
    Variable.set(key=DAG_ID, value=new_value, serialize_json=True)


last_loaded = Varible.get(key=var_name) # don't do this in production. Use macro instead.
your_higher_boundary_param = datetime.now(tz=None)

op1 = YourOperaror(
    task_id='op1_task',
    params = {"param1":last_loaded,
             param2: your_higher_boundary_param }
)
op2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='set_dag_variable_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=set_dag_variables,
    op_kwargs={'var_value': your_higher_boundary_param}
    )
op1 >> op2
```

Note: this is very high level and the details do matter!

For example I used `Varible.get` outside of operator/macro scope which is a bad practice. The proper way is to use macro but I simplified it for the propose of the example.

Comment: Thank you Elad. I am going with Variable solution and so far it works fine